# Updating Multiple Rows in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, sql-update

I can insert multiple rows in the database, but the problem is when I am trying to update it gives me a Codeigniter error message. Here is my model, actually I have nothing significant in the controller to find an error in, is because I just load that model in controller.

```
$data  = array();
//$todayDate = date('Y-m-d');
for($i = 1; $i < count($_POST['code']); $i++) {
    //$code=$_POST['code'][$i];
    if($_POST['code'][$i] != '') {
        $data[] = array(
            $code='code' => $_POST['code'][$i],
            'price' => $_POST['sell']
            );
    }
}
$linksCount = count($data);

if($linksCount) {
    $this->db->where('code',$code);
    $this->db->insert_batch('sell_rate', $data);
}

return $linksCount;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Model` following part should be

```
$data[] = array(
    $code='code' => $_POST['code'][$i],
    'price' => $_POST['sell']
);
```

replaced with

```
$data[] = array(
    'code' => $_POST['code'][$i],
    'price' => $_POST['sell']
);
```

and to update the values you should use `update_batch` instead of `insert_batch`

```
$this->db->update_batch('yourtableName', $data, 'code'); // 'code' is where key
```

Replace `yourtableName` with your original table name and `code` is being used for `where` key, so you don't need to use `$this->db->where('code',$code)`.

**Reference:** [**CodeIgniter**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html).

Comment: it gives an error unknown column Array in the field list.its trying to insert the "Array" not the data inside the Array

Comment: your code works thanks vaia.but there will be a slight change. It will be 'price'=>$POST['sell'][$i]

Comment: I have a problem,if i don't post anything sell field for the code it will set the code price to 0.but i want to keep it to its previous value.it means if i dont put any value for a code it will keep its previous value.please help me fixing this

Comment: I think you can check for both like `if($_POST['code'][$i] != '' && $POST['sell'][$i] !='')`

Comment: i don't need to check whither the code field is filled up or not. i want to check if i set any value for sell then it will run the query.so i tried as 'if($POST['sell'][$i] !='')
  {
  
  $this->db->where('code',$code);
  $this->db->update('sell_rate',$price);
  }
  else
  return false;' but its giving me as before a 0 value

Comment: Try `if($_POST['sell'][$i])` instead.

Comment: its giving me undefined offset:10 error.please can you tell me where to place that code.i have place it before the last if condition of my model code

Comment: Before `$data[] = array(...)` as `if($_POST['code'][$i] != '' && ..) {`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16206/discussion-between-rahat-islam-khan-and-sheikh-heera)