# Codeigniter batch update raises error about index

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, sql-update

The following code in codigniter gives me an error to update array:

```
$query="UPDATE sell_rate SET price='$price' WHERE code='$code'";
                $this->db->query($query);
```

The error is:

> You must specify an index to match on for batch updates

Please help me fixing this.

Comment: I got no clue about codeigniter, but I'd say you have to provide more information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating Multiple Rows in Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238941/updating-multiple-rows-in-codeigniter)

Comment: This error rise for db->update_batch() method, not for db->query()..

Comment: Why dont you use the active record?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

$options = array('price'=>$price);
      $this->db->where('code', $code);
      $this->db->update('sell_rate', $options);